# Switch Orientation of Rows/Columns in Grid, Column layout constructs

Tags: grid-layouts, column

Column layout construct has the BaselinePosition option where you can specify the origin placement for the "bars", e.g. Bottom (Vertical orientation).

Here is some data to play with:

```
wrdBars = {{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", 
"eight"}, {"one", "two", "three", "four"}, {"one", "two", "three",
 "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven",
 "twelve"}, {"one", "two", "three"}, {"one", "two", "three", 
"four", "five", "six", "seven"}, {"one", "two", "three", "four", 
"five"}};
```

I can get a nice horizontal orientation of my word bars with alternating background using

```
Column[#, Background->{{LightRed, LightGreen}}, Frame->All]& @ wrdBars
```

and I can switch to vertical orientation, although I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, with

```
Column[#, BaselinePosition->Bottom, Frame->All] & /@ wrdBars
```

although I am missing the alternating background for each bar, how can I get this ?

And how can I use a Grid construct to get a similar presentation on my data  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bob has shown one way to set the `Background` property of `Column`. Here is another way:

```
coloredColumn[list_, {i_}] := Column[list,
  BaselinePosition -> Bottom,
  Frame -> All,
  Background -> If[EvenQ[i], LightGreen, LightRed]
  ]
Row[MapIndexed[coloredColumn, wrdBars], Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use `Item` to style cells individually, and it could look like this (could also be written with `If` like above instead of having two definitions of `color`):

```
Clear[color]
color[el_, {_?OddQ, _}] := Item[el, Background -> LightRed]
color[el_, {_?EvenQ, _}] := Item[el, Background -> LightGreen]

coloredBars = MapIndexed[color, wrdBars, {2}];
Row[Column[#, BaselinePosition -> Bottom, Frame -> All] & /@ coloredBars, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Coloring the rows in each bar is a bit more difficult because we have to transform the row index before we can test if it is even or odd counted from the bottom as opposed to from the top.

```
Clear[color]
color[el_, pos_] := Item[el, Background -> color[wrdBars, pos]]

color[list_List, {i_, j_}] := With[{len = Length@Part[list, i]},
  If[OddQ[len - j], LightRed, LightGreen]
  ]

coloredBars = MapIndexed[color, wrdBars, {2}];
Row[Column[#, BaselinePosition -> Bottom, Frame -> All] & /@ coloredBars, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order to use `Grid` I'll first color the list of words, then pad it so that it's a rectangular matrix, and then transpose it.

```
padded = PadLeft[#, Max[Length /@ wrdBars], ""] & /@ coloredBars;
Grid[Transpose@padded]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works regardless of what coloring function you have applied. Note that you can provide styling for this grid either at the cell level, by modifying `color`, or at the grid level, by providing options to `Grid`.

Comment: I think you should reverse the order at each column in order to align the words. It is better presented this way, this is also what Bod did.

Comment: @Athanassios More importantly, it's not what **you** did in your question. You presented it as if the formatting was what you wanted, except for the coloring. It is easily done with `Reverse`, I'll leave it as an exercise.

Answer (score 5):

```
wrdBars = 
  Range@{8, 4, 12, 3, 7, 5} /. 
   Thread[Range[12] -> {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
      "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"}];

n = 0; Row[
 Column[#, BaselinePosition -> Bottom, Frame -> All, 
    Background -> If[EvenQ[n++], LightRed, LightGreen]] & /@ 
  Reverse /@ wrdBars]
```

[image]